# is there a way to use fgets size dynamically

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof, fgets

So im learning about pointers and dynamic memory and how am experimenting with fgets.

So i want to take in a string input into a pointer using fgets, but i want fgets size to change dynamically with malloc function that i used for the pointer is there a way to do it ?
e.g.

```
int main(){
    char *text;
    text =(char *)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(text, n, stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation**

1. I created a char pointer called 'text' to eventually store the string.
2. I then use malloc planning to store 200 characters
3. Next i want to use fgets to take in the string input by the user
   **Where 'n' is the size of text that malloc allocated for the pointer?**

i have tried `fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);` but it does not work ?

Comment: `fgets(text, n, stdin);` : what is `n`?

Comment: A straight forward solution would be to store the size in `n`, then use `n` for `malloc` and for `fgets`. What specifically don't you like with that?

Comment: A common beginner mistake is to be overly concerned about a few 100 bytes here and there. Don't worry about such things as optimizing memory use or speed while you are still learning the basics.

Comment: Or do you want to ba able to read lines of any size and have the buffer dynamically allocated according to the size of the line read via `fgets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work since `sizeof(ptr)` where ptr is a dynamic pointer to a char array will always be size of pointer (8 for 64bits machines), not size of array. You would have to:

- either store 200 in some kind of variable; or
- statically allocate memory for text, like `char text[200];`

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to allocate some upper bounded size buffer and then right-size it.

```
char *fgets_alloc(FILE *f, size_t max_size) {
  char *buf = malloc(max_size);
  if (buf) {
    if (fgets(buf, max_size, f)) {
      size_t sz = strlen(buf) + 1;
      void *ptr = realloc(buf, sz);  // Reduce allocation
      if (ptr) {
        buf = ptr;
      }
      return buf;
    }
    free(buf);
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

To Do: code to handle excessively long lines and `max_size` outside `int` range.